# Change cursor on hovering inline content in a selectable RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, richtextbox

I'm developing an UWP app but I kinda got stuck.

I am trying to show a different cursor icon when hovering the `Image` inside the `InlineUIContainer` but I just can't get it to work since the RichTextBlock changes the cursor to the standard "Text-cursor" when I hover it.

I **can** solve this (to some extent) and change the cursor icon with this code **if** I set the property `IsTextSelectionEnabled` to `False`
but since I need the content of the RichTextBox to be selectable I can't do that.

I was kinda wondering if there are some way to solve this by disabling `IsTextSelectionEnabled` and handle/capture the selection events myself but I have no idea how I would do something like that since I'm kinda new to the RichTextBlock control.

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock">
    <Paragraph>
        <Span>Hellu</Span>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image
                Source="{ Binding url }"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                PointerEntered="Image_PointerEntered"
                PointerExited="Image_PointerExited" />
        </InlineUIContainer>
    <Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Code behind

```
private void Image_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Hand, 0);
}

private void Image_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time investigating this behavior (And playing around with `Interaction.Behavior` to do som XAML-only triggers), it seems there is no straight forward solution.

The only thing that comes close to a solution is something like this:

```
private TextPointer _start, _end;

        private void Image_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
            this._start = this.richTextBlock.SelectionStart;
            this._end = this.richTextBlock.SelectionEnd;
            this.richTextBlock.IsTextSelectionEnabled = false;
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Hand, 1);
        }

        private void Image_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
            this.richTextBlock.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
            this.richTextBlock.Select(this._start, this._end);
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);
        }
```

When the pointer enters, the current selection is saved and the `IsTextSelectionEnabled` is set to false. After leaving the pointer everything is set to the origin.

Not pretty but it might work